# How to store a full email message in django

Tags: email, django-models

This is kinda hard to google, so I'm asking here... How would you go about storing a whole email as a django model? I'm planning to archive an email message to a database (parts may also end up in files on disk).

Since I'd like to store as much info about it as possible (while still being searchable), I'd be happy if someone already did the hard work. Only just storing body and the most relevant fields would not be enough in my case.

So the question is: Is there a django app that already provides the models to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001/storing-email-messages-in-a-database) covering models for email messages in general (not Django-specific). For Django models, see the 
[`Message`](https://github.com/latestrevision/django-mailbox/blob/master/django_mailbox/models.py#L289) model in **django-mailbox**, which looks like the most relevant app listed in the email-related grid on [Django Packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/email/).